# How to use web page scheduler in C#.net

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

In one .aspx webpage I have 2 contacts details in two different <div> like below

```
<div id="primaryContact"> 
    Name - betty quay 
    Cell - 9867452389
    designation - Build 
</div>

<div id="secondryContact"> 
    Name - francesco maitire 
    Cell - 9867452389
    designation - Build 
</div>
```

Here I want to show each div on alternate day of a week.
How can I do so, using ASP.NET or Javascript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it in C# like this:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ShowContactAlternate();
    }

    private void ShowContactAlternate()
    {
        if ((int)DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek % 2 == 0)
            primaryContact.Visible = true;
        else
            secondaryContact.Visible = true;
    }
```

Also make sure that you change your markup to something like this and add `runat="server` and `Visible="False"` attributes to divs":

```
<div id="primaryContact" runat="server" Visible="False"> Name - betty quay Cell - 9867452389 designation - Build </div>
<div id="secondryContact" runat="server" Visible="False"> Name - francesco maitire Cell - 9867452389 designation - Build </div>
```

EDIT:

If you want to alternate every week you can do it like this probably:

Create this helper function:

```
private int GetWeekOfYear(DateTime date)
{
    return CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Calendar.GetWeekOfYear(date, 
            CalendarWeekRule.FirstFourDayWeek,
            DayOfWeek.Monday);
}
```

And you can use it in your if statement inside `ShowContactAlternate` line this:

```
if (GetWeekOfYear(DateTime.Now) % 2 == 0)
```

As every year has 52 weeks you have to be sure that you don't run in to trouble every new year. It shouldn't be a problem to solve.

Comment: Good try but it will cause problem when date is 31 and so the next day will 1 and it will show same div in both this day...
But well try I had thanked this thing first...

Comment: You are right... Haven't thought of that one.... I've changed my code so it watches for a day of week 0-6 (Monday to Sunday) so you won't have that problem anymore.

Comment: I don't see a problem with this newly suggested solution as DayOfWeek is an Enumeration of days in a 7 day week. How does having 31 days in a month effect this?

Comment: @Mez I've edited my solution. It was just `DateTime.Now.Day` at first.

Comment: Yep looks like my comment came in after you changed your answer but before you posted a comment saying you changed it. DayOfWeek is one way to go in solving this problem

Comment: thanks alot ttkalec
if i want to change it on weekly basis then what i need to do?
means alternate week it should change the div

Comment: @picnic4u I've updated my answer for your request. Hope it helps.

Comment: `return System.Globalization.Calendar.GetWeekOfYear(
            date,
            CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.CalendarWeekRule,
            CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.FirstDayOfWeek
        );`
After using code as above, i m getting below error
An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'System.Globalization.Calendar.GetWeekOfYear(System.DateTime, System.Globalization.CalendarWeekRule, System.DayOfWeek)'

Comment: @picnic4u Take a look at my code... I've edited it once again so it's easier to understand which Class `GetWeekOfYear` function belongs to. Be sure to reference `System.Globalization` like on top of your C# file like this: `using System.Globalization;`

Comment: @ttkalec - thanks alot now working
i was using earlier like
`CultureInfo cal = new CultureInfo("ar-SA");
return cal.Calendar.GetWeekOfYear(
date,
CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.CalendarWeekRule,
CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.FirstDayOfWeek
);`
working :)